# How can I control the ingestion rate to my RDS when using ETL jobs for aws glue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, etl, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I am using the AWS glue ETL job which will read data from the glue catalog and write it to the database. I want to limit the rate of writing the record to my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well while writing to your RDS using JDBC connection, you can change the batchSize parameter.

batchSize is responsible for ingestion rate.

If you want more detail please update your code.